# close a js 'lightbox' type overlay

Tags: javascript

I am using PrettyPhoto to display a contact form. I wanted the 'close' button to be inline with the other text, and I couldn't get it quite right through the css, is there a way to make the word 'close' shut down the lightbox, the way I have it laid out currently?

http://gherkin.co.nz/gg/emailtest.php

Click on 'send us an email' at the bottom of the page.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this on the prettyPhoto support forum:

http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=9&page=1#Item_8

Here is a quote from the link above regarding the solution. If you follow the link there is a code sample.

> Sadly you cannot call
>   $.prettyPhoto.close(); from inside an
>   iFrame. It is consider as a security
>   treat to let iframe loaded pages
>   interact with the parent.
>
> However, there's a workaround. What
>   you can do is add a listener in your
>   parent page, a timer that check every
>   10ms if the location.hash has changed.
>   If the location.hash has changed and
>   if it's your value,
>   "#close-prettyphoto" for example. Then
>   call $.prettyPhoto.close(); Now in
>   your iframe, when you want to close
>   prettyPhoto, you just need to change
>   the top.location.hash.
>
> It's a bit hacky, but it's workking.